# Adding two joined numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find out how is it possible to add or multiply two joined characters or numbers. For example, the user inputs a number 83. Now how can we add 8 and 3(that is 11)?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you take input from a user,it is in **string**
Then loop through that string and convert it to a integer and add it

```
number=input("Number is ")
ans=0
for i in number:
  ans+=int(i)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the integer into a string, split it apart into each digit, convert single digits to ints and then sum the list like so:

```
number = 83
sum_digits = sum(int(num) for num in str(number))
```

Comment: A string is already iterable, you don't need to convert it to a list -- `sum(int(num) for num in str(number))`

Comment: Thanks @MarkM, I will update answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

using `sum`

```
number = int(input())

sum_of_digits = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number))

print(sum_of_digits)
```

using `for-loop`:  take a user input. Create a `for-loop` to iterate over each `digit` in the `string`. Use `int()` to convert the `string` digit to an `integer`. Add this digit to the `sum` of the digits in each iteration:

```
number = input()
sum_of_digits = 0
for digit in number:
  sum_of_digits += int(digit)

print(sum_of_digits)
```

Comment: Why convert the original string to an integer only to convert it back to a string?

Comment: thanks for pointing the unnecessary casting. edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string - strings can be then treated as a list of characters and iterated over. Example:

```
user_input = 83 # integer
string_input = str(user_input)
list_of_integers = [int(x) for x in string_input]

sum_of_integers = sum(list_of_integers)

print(sum_of_integers)
# 11
```